# What mechanism can make a shaft rotate in steps

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I want to make a shaft rotate in 21 discrete steps, from a motor that is turning smoothly.

I am thinking of some kind of simplified clock escapement type of mechanism. Or non circular gears.

I know it could be done by programming a stepper motor. But it will be easier and more fun for me to do it mechanically with 3D printed nylon parts.

This is for a low torque low speed application. About 1 rpm and less than 0.1 Nm torque.

Comment: How about a Geneva mechanism ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Geneva drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_drive)
[3D Printed Geneva Drive](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:192448)

[image: Geneva drive]
[image]

[Anchor Escapement (Clock Mechanism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_escapement)
[3D Printed Anchor Escapement](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1128317)

[image]

Comment: Nice visualizations.

Comment: Regulating the radii ratio between the wheels of the Geneva mechanism you can tune the number of steps to a degree; at a high number of steps (like 21) you'd have a lot of play though, as the curve of the rounded part of the "star" wheel would be very shallow. But if you make the Geneva mechanism for 7 steps and then reduce this further by normal gears in 1:3 ratio, you'll have your 21 steps on output while keeping play to minimum.

Comment: How is a Geneva Drive implemented in real machinery? It appears to have a large contact area between static and moving items, leading to significant friction & wear.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The faces of the two wheels are not in contact. The only contact is between the pin and the slots on the indexing wheel. This creates a line contact. Depending on the loads and the size of the mechanism, this could be addressed in a number of ways or combinations of ways. The pin and the slot would likely be hardened. There would likely be lubrication. The pin might really be a roller bushing.

Comment: @DLS3141  ok, I see.  I thought the semicircular part was there to inhibit backlash in the red gear.  So why not just a regular toothed wheel for the red and a single-tooth gear for the driver?